redis (ledis) become slow after flushdb
I use the following command to clear the Ledis index.
from redis import StrictRedis
db_value = 7
redis = StrictRedis(host=HOST, **cloud_cfg, db=db_value)
redis.flushdb()

After I clear the index, I use following command:
from redis import StrictRedis
db_value = 7
redis = StrictRedis(host=HOST, **cloud_cfg, db=db_value)
res = redis.mget(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']) 

It takes 4 second.
But when I use mget in DB 8.
It only need 0.193 second.
My questions are:
1. Why my DB become slow after flushdb?
2. How can I fix it?

more information:
redis version(python): 4.5.4
ledis version(server): 1.3.8

I find that change mget_threshold to large than the number of mget is more useful.
--update--
I found that my ledis config has been customized, so it may not serve as a good reference.
However, the core idea behind this modification is that the original mget, when facing misses, uses an iterator for processing, which may not be very fast.
Therefore, we aim to increase the number of get operations to skip the iterator.

your answer is not clear, please provide clarification and/or with support of official Redis documentation

@GoranB. Thank you for your question. I have updated my answer.

FLUSHDB is sync by default, meaning it will delete keys one by one before returning.
Try ASYNC option
https://redis.io/docs/latest/commands/flushdb/
Starting with Redis version 4.0.0: Added the ASYNC flushing mode modifier

I found that after using mset to reset a large amount of data, the mget speed returned to normal. I still don't know why, but people encountering similar issues might want to give it a try.
